# Calculating pi in Python using geometry

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm posting this code with the hope that this community will be willing to assist me in ironing out some bugs I can't seem to be able to tackle. It's quite short, is intended to guess pi, and is not intended to replace already efficiently working approaches. This is not an assignment.

```
# this code is completely broken

from math import sqrt

def get_y(x, r):
    return sqrt((r^2.0)-(x^2.0))

def get_distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return sqrt( (x2-x1)^2.0 + (y2-y1)^2.0 )

def c(r):
    def range(b):
        a = 0
        while a < b:
            yield a
            a = a + 1
    circumference = 0.0
    for x1 in range(r):
        x2 = x1 + 1.0
        y1 = get_y(x1, r)
        y2 = get_y(x2, r)
        distance = get_distance(x1, y1, x2, x2)
        circumference = circumference + distance
    circumference = circumference * 4
    return circumference

print get_y(0, 4)
radius = 400.0
print "%.64f" % (c(radius) / radius * 2)
```

Comment: Could you give us an overview of how this code is going to go about "guessing" pi?

Comment: Just curious, why did you redefine `range`? There's a builtin function that does the same thing already...

Comment: Some specific errors or diffs between expected and actual output would be helpf... essential. One issue I can see instantly is the huge count of semicolons - whytheheckyoudontneedthempleaseremovetheminstantly.

Comment: It'll help if you share what mathematical theorem you are implementing here in approximating PI.

Comment: I suggest you read a Python tutorial because this is not Matlab with semicolons and a `^` exponentiation operator.

Comment: You mean, the [Monte Carlo Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method)?

Comment: This would be more on-topic at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "this code is completely broken".  Could you be more specific?

Comment: It looks like it computes pi by working out the length of a circle approximated by a number (equal to the radius) of short straight line segments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
# Not broken anymore, prints 3.1415559...

from math import sqrt

def get_y(x, r):
    return sqrt((r**2.0)-(x**2.0)) # First mistake: ** is exponentiation, not ^

def get_distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return sqrt( (x2-x1)**2.0 + (y2-y1)**2.0 )

def c(r):
    # def range(b): # redundant
    #     a = 0
    #     while a < b:
    #         yield a
    #         a = a + 1
    circumference = 0.0
    for x1 in range(r):
        x2 = x1 + 1.0
        y1 = get_y(x1, r)
        y2 = get_y(x2, r)
        distance = get_distance(x1, y1, x2, y2) # second mistake, x2, x2 --> x2, y2
        circumference = circumference + distance
    circumference = circumference * 4
    return circumference

print get_y(0, 4)
radius = 400.0
print "%.64f" % (c(radius) / (radius * 2)) # third mistake: / radius * 2 --> / (radius*2)
```

Comment: You can also use `circumference += get_distance(...)` and `circumference *= 4` to simplify.